# Java Swing cannot figure out a problem with JPanel when running the app in full-screen mode

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

The constructor of **MainPanel** class is not being accessed when I run the app in the full-screen mode. It is only being accessed when I click on any item from the menubar.

The app runs fine in windowed mode or when I manually set the frame's width and height.

[app running in windowed-mode or when I set width and height (working fine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztgSV.png)

[app running in full-screen mode but the MainPanel() constructor is not being called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXn8j.png)

[app running in full-screen mode after clicking on any of the menu item (the MainPanel() constructor in called)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWN5R.png)

**Main.java**

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AppFrame mainFrame = new AppFrame("Algorithm Visualizer");
            mainFrame.add(new MainPanel());
        }
    }
```

**MainPanel.java**

```
    public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
        MainPanel() {
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

**AppFrame.java**

```
    class AppFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
            private JMenuBar menuBar;
            private JMenu fileMenu, sortingAlgoMenu, searchingAlgoMenu;
            private JMenuItem exitItem, bubbleSortItem;
        
            // constructor with frame_title and auto app resolution
            AppFrame(String frameTitle) {
                // sets the app theme
                setTheme();
        
                // Frame Properties
                this.setTitle(frameTitle);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setResizable(false);
        
                GraphicsDevice myDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
            
                // this is the code that makes the frame full-screen
                if(myDevice.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                    this.setUndecorated(true);
                    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                }
                else {
                    // windowed mode (title bar present)
                    int deviceWidth = myDevice.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
                    int deviceHeight = myDevice.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
                    
                    this.setSize(deviceWidth, deviceHeight);
                    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }
        
                // adds the MenuBar
                addMenuBar();
        
                // makes the JFrame visible
                this.setVisible(true);
            }
        
            // constructor passed with app title, width and height
            AppFrame(String frameTitle, int frameWidth, int frameHeight) {
                // sets the app theme
                setTheme();
        
                // Frame Properties
                this.setTitle(frameTitle);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setResizable(false);
                this.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
                this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
                // adds the MenuBar
                addMenuBar();
        
                // makes the JFrame visible
                this.setVisible(true);
            }
        
            // sets the theme of the application
            private static void setTheme() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        
            //  setting the JMenuBar
            private void addMenuBar() {
                menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        
                fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
                menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        
                sortingAlgoMenu = new JMenu("Sorting Algorithms");
                searchingAlgoMenu = new JMenu("Searching Algorithms");
        
                menuBar.add(sortingAlgoMenu);
                menuBar.add(searchingAlgoMenu);
        
                exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                bubbleSortItem = new JMenuItem("Bubble Sort");
        
                fileMenu.add(exitItem);
                sortingAlgoMenu.add(bubbleSortItem);
        
                // on-click of "Exit" 
                exitItem.addActionListener(this);
        
                this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            }
        
            // handle action events (on-click listeners)
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == exitItem)
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Components need to be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: I don't know what the difference between the two modes is. Forget abut the difference and learn how to use Swing effectively and you won't have a problem between the two modes. Swing components have a size of (0, 0) until the layout manager is invoked. The layout manager is invoked when the frame is made visible (or packed). If you add components to a visible frame, then you need to revalidate() and repaint() the panel you add the components to so the layout manager is invoked.

Comment: @camickr Thanks understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the MainPanel in the app frame right before addMenuBar(). The constructor is called anyways but the MainPanel is not visible the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. I was making the JFrame visible before adding the JPanel. So, I just removed the frame visibility from the AppFrame class and set its visibility(true) from Main.class after adding the JPanel.